# Forwarding traffic from port ttyS3 to ttyUSB0 - input/output error

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, forwarding

I am attempting to set up a basic pipe that'll transfer all data written to ttyS3 to ttyUSB0. I found a few solutions to the problem such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96718/how-do-i-use-a-serial-port-on-linux-like-a-pipe-or-netcat), but they don't seem to help much. The issue seems to be that anytime I do anything with ttyS3, I get this:

`stty: /dev/ttyS3: Input/output error`

Doing `ls -l /dev/ttyS*` and the same for `/dev/ttyUSB*` I get the following:

```
root@arm-64:~# ls -l /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Feb  9 13:08 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Feb  9 13:08 /dev/ttyS1
crw--w---- 1 root tty     4, 66 Feb  9 13:08 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 Feb  9 13:08 /dev/ttyS3
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 68 Feb  9 13:08 /dev/ttyS4
```

```
root@arm-64:~# ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb  9 13:08 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I've created the following script to do the job for me at startup. I changed the major/minor values to match that of `USB0` after reading somewhere that this could work as a pipe. Although it does execute without throwing an `Input/output error`, it doesn't seem to work as intended.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rm /dev/ttyS3
mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS3 c 188 0
chown root.dialout /dev/ttyS3
chmod 666 /dev/ttyS3
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 115200 cs8
stty -F /dev/ttyS3 speed 115200 cs8
cat /dev/ttyS3 > /dev/ttyUSB0 &
```

I just need to create a basic pipe that'll take all data written to `ttyS3` and pass it on to `ttyUSB0`. Although I don't think it's relevant, I'm running Armbian bullseye on a TV box (Tx3 Mini)

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to create a basic pipe that'll take all data written to ttyS3 and pass it on to ttyUSB0

Don't see a problem so long as each serial terminal is properly setup and functional/operational.  Before you create the "pipe", did you verify that each serial terminal is operating properly?

On a SBC I have the console on a serial terminal, and established two more serial terminals using a SoC USART and a USB adapter:

```
# ls -l /dev/tty*S*                                      
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 246,  0 Jan  1  2012 /dev/ttyGS0                      
crw------- 1 root tty       4, 64 Jul 31 22:46 /dev/ttyS0                       
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4, 65 Jul 31 22:25 /dev/ttyS1                       
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  0 Jul 31 22:28 /dev/ttyUSB0                     
#
```

Note that the **udev** daemon created these device nodes, and no funny business (i.e. manual re-creating device nodes) was necessary to accomplish the "pipe".

To remove canonical processing, each serial terminal is put in raw mode and with matching baudrates:

```
# stty raw 115200 -F /dev/ttyUSB0
# stty raw 115200 -F /dev/ttyS1
```

A report of all termios settings:

```
# stty -aF /dev/ttyUSB0                                  
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;                                 
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;           
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;  
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;                       
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts                 
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8                                                   
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt   
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc                                                 
#

# stty -aF /dev/ttyS1                                    
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;                                 
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;           
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;  
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;                       
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts                 
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8                                                   
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt   
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc                                                 
#
```

Then when the command

```
# cat /dev/ttyS1 > /dev/ttyUSB0 &
```

is issued, whatever is typed on the remote terminal-emulator program connected to **/dev/ttyS1** shows up on the remote terminal-emulator program connected to **/dev/ttyUSB0**.
This seems to behave like the desired *"basic pipe that'll take all data written to ttyS? and pass it on to ttyUSB0"*.

Bottom line:
Unable to duplicate problems, and can create "pipe" of two serial links.

```
# uname -a                                               
Linux sama5d2-xplained 5.4.81-linux4sam-2020.10 #1 Thu Jan 14 12:54:56 UTC 2021 
armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux                                                  
#
```

---

> The issue seems to be that anytime I do anything with ttyS3, I get this:
>
> ```
> stty: /dev/ttyS3: Input/output error
> ```

> ... I'm running Armbian bullseye on a TV box (Tx3 Mini)

As previously mentioned, you need to verify that each serial terminal is operating properly.
Since a *"TV box"* doesn't really need *five* (!) serial terminals, you might be seeing/creating bogus device nodes that don't have any hardware to access.
Search the system log for the actual hardware that was initialized, e.g. 'dmesg | grep tty'.  One of those UARTs might be used to interface to an IR receiver.

Comment: First of all, I greatly appreciate the lengthy reply. You are correct when you say that it's creating bogus psuedo-terminals. The problem however is that I have to use ttyS3 so the software I'm working on will be backwards compatible. For now, I used a basic socat command to link the two: `socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS3 PTY,link=/dev/ttyUSB0 &`